# Access local variable from other function PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a private function which has lots of variables, let's say these: `$foo`, `$bar`, `$baz`.

Inside the function, I call `parent::_setViewVars(array('foo','bar','baz'));`

This `_setViewVars` looks so:

```
protected function _setViewVars($a){
    foreach($a as $v){
        global $$v;
        $this->set($v, $$v);
    }
}
```

I just want to get rid off cakephp's shit like 80 lines of `$this->set('selected_areas',$selected_areas);`, that's what this function is for.

`_setViewVars` cannot access `$$v`, because it's not a global variable. Given that this function is being called from the context that has these variables, can I reach them somehow?

(by the way if there is a cakephp way of bulk setting view variables with the same names, tell me how -- I haven't found one)

PS: packing everything into an array is NOT a solution, we're talking about thousands of unneccessary square brackets here.

Comment: Take a look at [compact](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php), which creates array useful for your scenario.

Comment: I've tried it: `compact` also does not reach these variables.

Comment: Can you redefine `parent::_setViewVars`? Or skip calling it altogether in favor of your own loop in which you call `->set()`, dealing with output of `compact`?

Comment: `global`? Seriously? Just use `compact()` in your _controller actions_ (not in a redundant separate method): `$this->set(compact('foo', 'bar', 'baz'));` That's btw exactly what CakePHP does when baking controllers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is actually pretty standard PHP:

[`compact()`  -  Create array containing variables and their values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

Example showing it's use in a CakePHP Action:

```
$var1 = "I";
$var2 = "love";
$var3 = "pizza!";
$this->set(compact('var1', 'var2', 'var3'));
```

(might want to try to tone down the hatred a bit - you're more likely to get help that way)